# Time Series and regression analysis online course

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, references

I am going to pursue my PhD in Data Science. My BS and MS degrees are in Mathematics. I would like to learn some self-paced statistics online courses to make my PhD journey more comfortable. I never took any undergrad/grad courses on time series, and regression analysis. I was wondering if you could tell me some good online resources (video lectures) about time series, and regression analysis. I sincerely appreciate your favor.

Comment: There are many similar Questions on this site. Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/learning-material-about-time-series,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/looking-for-a-mathematical-book-on-probability-and-statistics,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27553/the-reference-book-for-statistics-with-r-does-it-exist-and-what-should-it-cont, ... but starting out you should not only focus on web material. And also, download, install, learn R! Find a good data analysis project.

Comment: I am mostly looking for video lectures!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking into Econometrics. Its essentially applied data analysis that focusses heavily on regression analysis. You should probably start by using R as the above comment mentioned. There is a free online [course](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/) available that works you through a few basic examples with in browser programming.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend ( shamelessly since I wrote it !) https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf which focuses on some of the differences between cross-sectional regression analysis and the more frequent time-series regression analysis.